# Laravel - Error con rutas relativas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6, laravel-7

tengo esta estructura en un proyecto de laravel.
En la parte izquierda de la imagen os muestro la estructura de carpetas y en la parte derecha os muestro como cargo los css y js en un archivo "head.blade.php" que cargo en el layout de la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta si accedo a una ruta sin niveles tipo **http://test.local/informes** me carga bien estos archivos pero si hago una ruta con 2 niveles tipo  **http://test.local/informes/albaranes** si miro el console del chrome me da errores que no encuentra las rutas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el helper asset(), este helper te ubica siempre en la carpeta principal de la app.

Ejemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
//Te devuelve un url http://tudominio.com/js/jquery.js en cualquier ruta o lugar de la app donde te encuentres.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es el helper que estava buscando. 1000 gracias